# Show that if $A$ is path-connected subset of $X$, then $A\subset\text{PCmp}(x)$ for some $x\in X$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson.

The problem statement is in the title, where $\text{PCmp}(x)$ is the path component of $x$, defined as the set of all points in $X$ that may be connected to $x$ by a path in $X$.

I know that since $A$ is path connected that for any two elements in $A$, there is a path connecting them. To show that $A\subset\text{PCmp}(x)$, I need to pick an arbitrary element from $A$ and show that there is path connecting to $x$. This is where I have trouble, since I know $x$ would have to be in $X\setminus A$, since it would be trivial if $x$ where in $A$, due to $A$ being path connected.

What I'm thinking of doing is having a path which connects $a$ to $b$, were both $a,b\in A$, but with using $x$ as a guide between them. That way, both $a$ and $b$ are in $\text{PCmp}(x)$. Yet, I feel that since $A$ is path connected in the relative topology, all paths must lie within $A$. Does my approach even make sense or am I completely off track?

Thanks for help or hints!

Comment: Why must $x$ not be in $A$? Sometimes the answer *is* trivial. ;)

Comment: Well, I figure that if $x$ was in $A$ then since $A$ is path connected, every element connects to $x$, which would mean that $A\subset\text{PCmp}(x)$. But if it were the case, wouldn't it be mentioned that way and not with $x\in X$?

Comment: Yup, that's the proof. The original statement is essentially "If $A$ is path-connected then $A$ is a subset of one of the path components of $X$", which seems like a more natural statement than the (a priori stronger) "If $A$ is path-connected then $A$ is a subset of the path component containing $x$ for any $x\in A$".

Comment: So what if $x$ isn't in $A$? Wouldn't there need to be a proof for that case as well?

Comment: The statement is quantified by "for some $x$"; so to prove it we just have to exhibit a single $x$ for which the property holds.

Comment: Huh. So we just found that $x$ and it worked and so we're okay. So it would be a completely different proof then to find an $x\in X\setminus A$?

Comment: Yes, and in fact the statement "For all path-connected $A \subset X$ there is an $x \in X\setminus A$ such that $A \subset \rm{PCmp}(x)$" is not true - consider the case when A is a path component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer is trivial as you wrote "for some $x \in X$" and $x \in A$ will do the work .
As for every $x \in X$ i think that the statement will be incorrect.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the response!

Comment: it was nothing,by the way Hendrix RULESSS :D

Comment: Haha, yes, yes he does!